# Run all sagas found inside folder automagically

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a bunch of sagas in a folder, I reference them individually after creating my store and run them like so:

```
import authenticationSagas from './sagas/abcSaga'
import membershipCRUDSagas from './sagas/membershipCrud'
import classTimeSagas from './sagas/classTimeSagas'

// configure store/middlewhere, etc
// then run sagas:
sagaMiddleware.Run(authenticationSagas)
sagaMiddleware.Run(membershipCRUDSagas)
sagaMiddleware.Run(classTimeSagas)
```

is there a way to simply read in all the sagas in the folder 'sagas' and run them without having to lay them out like this? Ideal use case is if someone defines a saga in the sagasf older (or a subdirectory thereof) it will be found and run without any more work or effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check the awesome implementation by [React-Boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) project here - 


https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/98f5c0e5bc54a5540466515e38dea9e9cb752019/app/utils/injectSaga.js#L1

Hope this helps!